# Why does the program exit main loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following code that transmits the essence of the problem:

```
var body = "";
for(var i=0; i<=5000; i++) {
  body += "if(str==='value" + i + "') 1==1;\n";
}
body += "return str;";

var f1 = new Function("str", body);
var f2 = new Function("str", body);

console.log(f1('test1'));
console.log(f2('test2'));

// main loop
for(var i=0; i<100000; i++) {
  f1("string");
  f2("string");
  console.log(i);
}

console.log("fin!");
```

Why the main loop cycle does not work out until the end, and the program exits (thus no error information is not displayed)?

PS line "fin!" will not be displayed.

My nodejs version is 5.0.0

My actual output:

```
test1
test2
1
2
3
.
.
~1971
```

Comment: ... What are you trying to achieve with this? It looks like some major hacks are in play.

Comment: Post the entire function and the outputs you do get.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to accomplish but running this code produces "fin" at the end...

Comment: I have a million strings and i want to check them to ~10000 conditions...

Comment: Your function does not do anything though, just returning the same string that is passed in

Comment: My number stopped at 2852 and stopped not only my browser, but my whole Ubuntu VM. Thanks for that. I'm currently not sure why. I think it might be a callstack overflow, but that should actually throw.

Comment: @Dragos, what your nodejs version?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var i = 0;    
for(i=0; i < 5001; i++) {
      body += "if(str==='value" + i + "') 1==1;\n";
    }
```

But i think the functions are bugged...